# How to prevent Resharper 6 "Error saving solution settings" dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, resharper-6.0

My team uses VS 2010 Ultimate with TFS and we recently upgraded to Resharper 6.  Now every time I close my solution, I get this Resharper error dialog:

[image]

No one else here seems to get this but me.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Also, I'm not affecting this file directly so it must be something in Resharper that is making changes, maybe per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mrchief, thanks for your help! I do have permissions to edit the file.  Someone else had added it when he installed R# 6 on his pc.  His R# options were set to save the cache in the solution folder, as were mine, so here's what I ended up doing:

1. I opened the solution, checked out the file directly
2. I closed the solution with the file checked out: no error!
3. I checked in the file with the solution closed.
4. With the solution still closed, I set my Resharper options to save my cache in my system TEMP folder
5. Reopened the solution; now when I close, no error!

Comment: Post this as an update to your question so that future visitors can benefit. Do not forget to upvote/accept as answer if it helped you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for some reason, you do not have write access to the path. Either it's readonly or is restricted by your administrator.

You can try to save the files in your solution folder instead:

[image]

Comment: I've tried that already.  I get the error with caches set for TEMP or solution.

Comment: Can check to see if you have write permission on the folder and all its parent folders? Also, check if resharper files are marked readonly.

Comment: I'm an admin on my pc so I definitely have write permissions AND I have VS 2010 set so that I run it as an administrator. Resharper files are part of the solution in TFS so it must be file permissions in TFS.

Comment: Weird as it may sound, but another admin can _deny_ access to you for any folder/files. Check the access and readonly flag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had same problem where I was moving to different TFS 2010 servers

0) Move the temp file from Solution to temp dir as mentioned above 
1) Add the xxxxxx.ReSharper.user to the solution manually 
2) remove the readonly attribute from the file xxxxxx.ReSharper.user.

- I did step 2 when I went to exit and got the "Error saving" prompt then hit "try again" and all is fine now.

TFS/Source safe leave the file attributes in a mess for Reshaper 6.0